# Create an Acronym of a string in PHP

Tags: php, preg-match, acronym

I want to create an Acronym of a string based on the string's value. For instance if the string has spaces like "Stackoverflow Community Forum", the acronym should be "SCF", but if there is no spaces in the string it should take the first 3 Letters of the word like "Stackoverflow" should be "STA".
Another part should include that if the string is only 2 characters long, it should add a random Alphanumeric letter, example if the string is "IT" it should add it as "ITA"

Here is what I have so far. Although if I take the spaces out, I get SSTA at my second If.

The Idea of this is, the Acronym should be only 3 characters and should include incrementing numbers at the back example STA001 and next acronym SFC002 etc.

```
$s = 'Stackoverflow Community Forum';

if(preg_match_all('/\b(\w)/',strtoupper($s),$m)) {
    $v = implode('',$m[1]);
    echo $v;
}
if(!preg_match_all('/^\S.*\s.*\S$/',$s))
{
    $v = strtoupper(substr($s,0,3));
    echo $v;
}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Is using preg_match a restriction? If it is not there are a lot of easier ways to do it.

Comment: Not at all . I just tried preg_match from research. But I am open to any method to doing this.

Comment: What would `Stackoverflow Community` give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code first uses the same regex to match the first chars of each word, but it then checks it there is only 1 value found.  If just 1 value it uses the first 3 chars of the whole string, otherwise just implodes the matched letters.

Then it loops till the string is 3 chars long, adding a random char each time (this allows for 1 char strings)...

```
// Test Values
$s = 'Stackoverflow Community Forum';
$s = 'Stackoverflow Community';
$s = 'Stackoverflow';
$s = 'IT';
$s = 'I';

$s =strtoupper($s);
if(preg_match_all('/\b(\w)/', $s,$m)) {
    if ( count($m[1]) === 1 )   {
        $v = substr($s,0,3);
    }
    else    {
        $v = implode('',$m[1]);
    }
}
else    {
    $v = '';
}
// Pad to 3 chars long.
while ( strlen($v) < 3 )    {
    $v .= chr( ord("A") + rand(0,25) );
}
echo $v;
```

Comment: This works amazingly. Thank you so much @NigelRen. I was to implement a incrementing unique value to each one, how will I implement that based on a previous value? Like SCF001 is the first one and SCF002 the second?

Comment: If you had something like `$v = 'SCF001';`, then `$v++` will give you `SCF002`.

Comment: I understand, Although when I specify it like ```$n = "001"; for($n=0;$n<6;$n++) echo $v + $number++;``` It ignores the "00" and just counts 1 2 3 etc.

Comment: You will need to add the `001` onto the string before doing the increment.

Comment: I have done that as well, it sees the 001 as part of the string and changes the acronym completely and still ignores the 00

Comment: You mean you did `$v = $v + "001";` and then `$v++` and it gave you something else?

Comment: Sorry @NigelRen, I've got it. 
```$cl_cd = $v;
$cl_cd .= "000";
$cl_cd++;
echo $cl_cd;```